# Auto-Scrolling a Listbox

Tags: c#

Hey there!
now first of all some might want to shout that there are hundreds of topics on this - and its true - but not for my special case...so please help me :)

I'll place the example code first so you get your own view of it before you read my explanation:

```
class cls1
{
    cls2.listadd("bla");
}

class cls2
{
    public static Bindinglist<string> list = new Bindinglist<string>();

    public static void listadd(string x)
    {
        list.Add(x);
    }
}


class Form1
{
    //here would be all the listbox settings
    private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox lb;

    lb.Datasource = cls2.list
}

class maincls
{
    static void main()
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1);
    }
}
```

So the situation is the following: I have a class with only a static list & a static procedure to add to this list (it's a console kind of output for many other classes, so it has to be accessible from several classes without reinstancing all the time).
Of course since different programclasses can 'log' into this list it always has to be updated, which is why I chose the BindingList so databinding between listbox and bindinglist always automatically updates the listbox.
-Which leads to my problem: as you know from many other posts concerning the scrollbar always keeps at the top when you add a new item to the listbox.
Now I know there are the two wonderful methods using either 
the .SelectedIndex method:

```
listBox.SelectedIndex = listBox.Items.Count - 1;
listBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

or the .TopIndex method:

```
listbox.TopIndex = listbox.Items.Count -1;
```

and they work wonderful - but here is my **Problem**:
-I cannot place those methods in cls2 after each add because it won't be able to access the non static listbox in Form1.
-If I place the methods in Form1 they would work but are not callable from cls2 since not static.
-If I place the methods in Form1 as static they again have that access problem.
-I cannot make the listbox completely static, since all the Form stuff wouldn't work then.
-There seems to be no event for listboxes that is called when data changes without human interaction.
-I cannot use the add-event of the BindingList since then again I have the access problem.

Another idea was to create a main form calling all the other ones including a void method containing those procedures but again...no access without instance, no access when static...

I think I'm trapped in a bit of circle here :P

I just hope you guys come up with some good idea for solving this problem....

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!!!

**Solution**: 4th answer....was to stupid for the system :P Sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create static event in the cls2 class (line ItemAdded). Raise it from listadd function. Subscribe to this event in Form1 constructor, and scroll listbox down in the event handler.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your fast answer...this sounds wonderful...i'd love to use an event for it....gonna try it right away....just curios what exactly do you mean by "subscribe to this event in Form1"? I'm not quite sure there...just going to try now... :)

Comment: Assuming that cls2 has static ItemAdded event, write in Form1: cls2.ItemAdded +=  press Tab and Visual Studio editor completes this, writing subscription code and event handler.

Comment: got it :) now that I read your first post it all seems so clear :P  So thanks a lot!!    Here's my solution fitting for the example: add to cls2:  -Edit had to save it to an own answer...formatting didn't work....

Comment: You can edit the question, if you want to share your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call a static function in Form or expose the SelectedIndex property.

```
public static void DoSomeListBoxStuff(int index) 
{ 
   // do something
}
```

Or

```
int SelectedIndex
{ 
   get  
   { 
      return ListBox1.SelectedIndex; 
   } 
   set 
   { 
      ListBox1.SelectedIndex = value; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your fast answer...I haven't tried it since Alex farber came up with a very nice event based solution...but thanks anyway!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a static field in cls2 that would hold the instance of the form1 class. Then through this object you can access the non static list box object or even better call a non static function in form1 class and let it scroll the ListBox.

Comment: oops now thats what happens when you hit return^^  well the problem I see with this, is that again if I create an instance of Form1 in a static function in cls2 then again this instance is not globally availible across cls2 so again I cannot call the non-static refreshing method in Form1  and I can't create an instance outside a function in a class without contructor and only static members....  or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: Don't create the instance of form1 in a function but create it as a field on the class level. You can initialize this field from a constructur.

Comment: Or create a public static field (again on the class level) in the form1 and initialize it with the instance of itself with 'this' keyword (from a constructor or mabe an event). Then you will be able to access it from the cls2 static members. This actually would be my choice how to do it as it seems very logical and obvious to me...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I get the system wrong here...but I wasn't able to edit my first post and when I wanted to post the end solution in comment to the answer it didn't format correctly...
So here's the solution fitting for my example...thanks a lot to all - especially Alex Farber!!

add to cls2:

```
  public static event EventHandler<EventArgs> added;
  //Here would be the line that adds a line to the Bindinglist
  added(new object(), EventArgs.Empty);
```

add to constructor of Form1:

```
cls2.added +=new EventHandler<EventArgs>(rescroll);
```

add to Form1, code part:

```
public void rescroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lb.SelectedIndex = lbcons.Items.Count - 1;
            lb.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
```